# Showing Selected Buttons if Back button is Pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

On first Page i am having some buttons , if i press any button it will move to Second page , here if i press back button in the navigation bar it will move to first page

i have created the buttons dynamically based on the array count ,i want to show the selected button when i move back to first page , how can i do this  ?Please help me to do this .here is the code that i have used for creating buttons

```
int buttonheight = 30;
int horizontalPadding = 20;
int verticalPadding = 20;

int totalwidth = self.view.frame.size.width;

int x = 10;
int y = 150;

for (int i=0; i<array.count; i++)
{

    NSString* titre = [array objectAtIndex:i];

    //
    CGSize contstrainedSize = CGSizeMake(200, 40);//The maximum width and height

    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0], NSFontAttributeName,
                                          nil];
    CGRect frame = [titre boundingRectWithSize:contstrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributesDictionary context:nil];
    int xpos = x + CGRectGetWidth(frame);

    if (xpos > totalwidth) {

        y =y +buttonheight+ verticalPadding;
        x = 10;


    }


    UIButton * word= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    self.word = word;

    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(frame));
    word = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    word.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, CGRectGetWidth(frame)+5, CGRectGetHeight(frame));
    [word setTitle:titre forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    word.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:30.0/255.0 green:134.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    [word setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    [word setTag:i];
    [word addTarget:self action:@selector(btn1Tapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    word.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    word.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    word.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

    [self.view addSubview:word];

    x =x+horizontalPadding+CGRectGetWidth(frame);

}
- (IBAction)btn1Tapped:(id)sender {

NSString *btnTitle;
btnTitle = [(UIButton *)sender currentTitle];
NSLog(@"%@",self.title);
ReasonViewController *ReasonVC = [self.storyboard     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ReasonVC"];
ReasonVC.btnTitle = btnTitle;
NSLog(@"%@",self.imageArray);
ReasonVC.imageArray1 = self.imageArray;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ReasonVC animated:YES];    
}
```

Comment: Are you recreating the, when you go back? Why are they deselected?

Comment: please add your button click method that is your btn1Tapped:

Comment: @TLuck i have updated my code with button click method

Comment: @user6183984 please see my code

Comment: You want to make selected button for 1 only or for all which are selected ?

Comment: @Hasya , I want to make selected button for 1 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=====Appdelegate.h========

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) long int btnTag;
```

=======CategoryViewController.h============

```
import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface CategoryViewController : UIViewController
{
    AppDelegate *appdel;
}
```

===========CategoryViewController.m=======
add code

```
if(appdel.btnTag == word.tag)
{
   word.selected = YES;
}
```

below `[word setTag:i];` code

then add

```
 UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) sender;
 appdel.btnTag = btn.tag;
```

in `- (IBAction)btn1Tapped:(id)sender` method

Comment: have you solved your problem @user6183984

Answer (score 1):

The UIButton object has different states included the "Selected state". You can set different background image or title for each state you want. When you press it you can change its state like this:

```
//After you inited your UIButton Object do this:
[button setBackgroundImage:selectedBGImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button setBackgroundImage:deselectedBGImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//You can also find the title change method for state accordingly


- (void)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender
{ 
  sender.selected = !sender.selected;
//TODO 
}
```

So, when you pop back, the button will keep its "selected" state.

Comment: Yes,Defiantly You Can Set Selected and Deselected Image For A Button And Change There State According to There Tapped.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store button tag in appdelegate and while creating button check with button tag/i values and do selected. please see below code

in AppDelegate.h

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) int btnTag;
```

create an object of AppDelegate on your current ViewController then

```
AppDelegate *appdel  = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
int buttonheight = 30;
.
.
.
    [word setTag:i];
    if(word.tag == appdel.btnTag)//appdel is object of AppDelegate
    {
         word.selected = YES;
    }
    [word addTarget:self action:@selector(btn1Tapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    word.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    word.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    word.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

    [self.view addSubview:word];

    x =x+horizontalPadding+CGRectGetWidth(frame);

}

    - (IBAction)btn1Tapped:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) sender;
    appdel.btnTag = btn.tag;
    NSString *btnTitle;
    btnTitle = [(UIButton *)sender currentTitle];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.title);
    ReasonViewController *ReasonVC = [self.storyboard     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ReasonVC"];
    ReasonVC.btnTitle = btnTitle;
    NSLog(@"%@",self.imageArray);
    ReasonVC.imageArray1 = self.imageArray;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ReasonVC animated:YES];    
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXMeD.png)
I am getting like below screenshot , if i tapped any button it will move to next page and the backgroundcolor is changed to red color,and come back to same page by clicking back  and now i tapped another button it is also showing in red color.
I have use this two lines in button action method :

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) sender;
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Thanks @TLuck , i will try and let you know

Comment: it showing error like use of undeclared identifier appdel.

Comment: have you add **@property (assign, nonatomic) int btnTag;** on **appdelegate.h** @user6183984

Comment: ,Ya . i have add property for btnTag

Comment: and what about **AppDelegate *appdel  = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];** 
have you added it?

Comment: i forgot to import the appdelegate.h file ,that error cleared but now , **appdel.btnTag = btn.tag;** in this line it is showing same error

Comment: and what about **AppDelegate *appdel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];** have you added it?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: please see my update code , it is not working fine

Comment: can you please share your project with me? so its easy to help.

Comment: can u please share ur mail id ,then i can able to share my files

Comment: tilakjethva@gmail.com

Comment: ,Check your mail , i have shared the link to your mail

Comment: ok i will check and let you know

Comment: Thanks @TLuck,i am waiting for your reply